# MySQL stored procedure without parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a procedure but it gives me syntax error. I am not certain of what seems to be the problem

```
        delimiter $$
        create
        procedure inactivity()
        LANGUAGE SQL
        begin
        [mysql block]
        end $$
        delimiter;
```

Comment: What is the error message and which line does it relate to?

Comment: @w5m, this is the error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create procedure question_inactivity()
begin
delete from questions_temp where ' at line 2

Comment: TIP: write each SQL statement properly, end line with `;`  wherever necessary , inside the [ mysql block ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. What was wrong is that there was no space between delimiter and the semicolon.

Answer (score 4):

Try this sql code:

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists question_inactivity;
create procedure question_inactivity()
begin
delete from questions_temp where active= 1;
update questions set active = 0 where question_id in(select question_id from questions_temp);
drop table questions_temp;
end $$
delimiter;
```

------------------------------UPDATE------------------------------------

I running this in phpmyadmin and it'works:

```
delimiter $$

create procedure question_inactivity()
begin
delete from questions_temp where active= 1;
update questions set active = 0 where question_id in(select question_id from questions_temp);
drop table questions_temp;
end 

$$
```

In the Delimiter input field i put this value: $$